# How to check if application has started inside container

Tags: docker

We have an integration test suite that starts containers before starting any test cases. we used to wait for port to be available before executing any tests, which indicated that application is ready to receive requests. But with version 1.7.1 ports are instantly available, before application has even started inside container.

Is there an option to postpone docker port forwarding until port is open inside container?

Or is there other reliable method to check if application has started inside container?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But with version 1.7.1 ports are instantly available, before application has even started inside container.

I don't think that's true -- that is, I think it depends on how you are trying to contact a port.  Consider, for example, a container like this:

```
$ docker run -it -p 8888:80 alpine sh
```

Here we've set up port forward from host port 8888 to container port 80, but we haven't set up anything to listen inside the container.  Trying to connect to port 8888 on `localhost` results in a successful connection that immediately closes:

```
$ telnet localhost 8888
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Which is exactly what you are experiencing.  But if instead of `localhost` we use an ip address of the host, we see different behavior:

```
$ telnet 192.168.1.55 8888
Trying 192.168.1.55...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.55: Connection refused
```

If inside the container I start a web server:

```
/ # apk add mini_httpd
[...]  
/ # mini_httpd 
mini_httpd: started as root without requesting chroot(), warning only
```

Then I can successfully connect:

```
$ telnet 192.168.1.55 8888
Trying 192.168.1.55...
Connected to 192.168.1.55.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

This happens because connections via `localhost` are handled by the Docker userland proxy, which is bound to port 8888:

```
# netstat -tlnp | grep 8888
tcp6       0      0 :::8888                 :::*                    LISTEN      2809/docker-proxy
```

But connections to another interface ip -- and any connection originating from another host -- will be handled by the rules in the iptables `nat` table:

```
# iptables -t nat -S DOCKER
-N DOCKER
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8888 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.138:80
```

> Or is there other reliable method to check if application has started inside container?

You have a few choices:

- Just connect to the container ip directly, rather than relying on port forwarding.  E.g., in the above example the container I started was assigned address 172.17.0.138.  I can just connect to that instead of a host address.  It's easy to find the ip address of a docker container:

  $ docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' my-container
  172.17.0.138
- Wait until you achieve a *successful* connection to your application.  In this example, in which I ultimately started a web server, I could wait until `curl` successfully connects:

  ```
  while ! curl -sf http://localhost:8888/; do
    sleep 1
  done
  ```

  The `-f` flag tells curl to exit with an error code if it cannot successfully fetch a URL.

Comment: + option to follow the log output of the container until the service prints out an indication of readiness to accept requests.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue which I solved with this Python script:

```py
    def is_port_connected_in_container(host, port):
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            s.settimeout(0.1)
            # try to connect; if it fails, port is closed
            try:
                s.connect((host, port))
            except socket.timeout:
                return False

            # try to receive some data
            try:
                received = s.recv(1)
            except socket.timeout:
                # no data, but this only times out if port was open
                return True

            # no timeout, so port open depends on whether we received something
            return len(received) > 0
```